# How do I build a dictionary of members with children from mysql in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am developing a unilevel Multi Level Marketing (MLM) application which stores data with mysql columns  *id, parent_id*

with each item having one parent. each item can have up to 50 children. Given a particular id, how do I get all its children and children of its children etc. and its parents and parent's parents, etc. I want to get this data into a dic and display. Thanks

Comment: It's fundamentally very difficult to query a hierarchy in MySQL consisting only of parent relationships. You should investigate other hierarchical data structures more suitable for MySQL, for example [nested sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

Comment: Thanks. will look it up. but in the mean time, how do I do it in code (python) to get all children or parents given an id